# sklearn Logistic Regression ValueError: X has 42 features per sample; expecting 1423

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nan, prediction

I'm stuck trying to fix an issue.
Here is what I'm trying to do :

I'd like to predict missing values (Nan) (categorical one) using logistic regression.
Here is my code :

df_1 : my dataset with missing values only in the "Metier" feature (missing values I'm trying to predict)

```
X_train = pd.get_dummies(df_1[df_1['Metier'].notnull()].drop(columns='Metier'),drop_first = True)
X_test = pd.get_dummies(df_1[df_1['Metier'].isnull()].drop(columns='Metier'),drop_first = True,dummy_na = True)

Y_train = df_1[df_1['Metier'].notnull()]['Metier']
Y_test = df_1[df_1['Metier'].isnull()]['Metier']

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)

classifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)

classifier.score(X_train,Y_train) = 0.705112088833019
```

BUT when I'm trying to get the prediction on `Y_test` It says :

> ValueError: X has 42 features per sample; expecting 1423

I would highly appreciate If someone could give me a hand.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The input vecotr for prediction (I would assume `Y_test`) , does not fit to your train vector `Y_train`, you can check it with `Y_test.shape`and `Y_train.shape`

Comment: When you use the parameter `dummy_na = True` on the `X_train`, you get extra columns (e.g features) for you x's. If you don't do that on `X_test`, you will have less columns there, and therefore get an error when it will try to apply on `X_test` the model reached on `X_train` (though the numbers seems too far away for that reason alone).

Comment: @ PV8 It doesn't fit because I'm trying to predict Nan mising values Y_test based on  existing values Y_train.

Comment: @Aryerez How could I deal with it ? Knowing that I'm trying to replace nan values in a column using a logistic regression ?

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb is to **never** use `pandas.get_dummies` on multiple dataframe. It does not guarantee you the same dimension.

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.get_dummies(['a', 'b', 'c']))
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1

print(pd.get_dummies(['b', 'c']))
   b  c
0  1  0
1  0  1
```

It is only safe if you do `pandas.get_dummies` **first** then divide into `x_train` and `x_test`. But instead, you can use `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)

ohe.fit_transform(np.reshape(['a', 'b', 'c'], (-1, 1)))

array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])

ohe.transform(np.reshape(['b', 'c'], (-1, 1))) # Its transform, NOT fit_transform
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Notice that now it properly asserts two different inputs result in the same number of columns.