# How to apply a scikit learn models to unseen data of a different shape? Get Dummies is causing problems

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dummy-variable

Let's say my training a model to detect churn, and the dataset has the following features (very simplified). I have makes and females, who have signed up online or by post.

```
ID  source  Gender  Churn
1   Online  M       1
2   Post    M       1
3   Online  M       1
4   Online  F       0
5   Post    F       0
```

And I apply pandas `get_dummies`:

```
ID  source_online   source_post Gender_M    Gender_F
1       1               0          1          0
2       0               1          1          0
3       1               0          1          0
4       1               0          0          1
5       0               1          0          1
```

Now let's say I use `StandardScaler` and then `fit` a model on this data and train it.

Some days later I get new data from the **same database & schema** and I have to predict churn. Exact same variables, except this time it has only males, who have only signed up online.

```
ID  source  Gender
1   Online  M
2   Online  M
3   Online  M
```

I apply `get_dummies`:

```
   ID  source_Online  Gender_M
0   1              1         1
1   2              1         1
2   3              1         1
```

First of all, the `StandardScaler` with the learned settings from the training set doesn't work on this unseen data, because it's missing some `dummy variables`. And of course it does not work with the trained model, because of the same reason.

Is there any way around this?

I currently have hundreds of records with this problem because they are missing a single within a variable that was present in the training set. (In this simplified example we are missing females)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335718/keep-same-dummy-variable-in-training-and-testing-data

Comment: Take a look at the answer I provided in this similar question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799643/sklearn-logistic-regression-valueerror-x-has-42-features-per-sample-expecting/58799980#58799980

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One hot encoding train with values not present on test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946006/one-hot-encoding-train-with-values-not-present-on-test)

Comment: @MaximeKan `OneHotEncoder` requires that I convert all my categorical to numbers first, such as Gender: M/F to Gender 1/0 etc etc. This isn't very convenient, and then I lose the column names after using `onehotencoder`, so there's another extra step involved to get the column names back. So I stayed with pandas `get_dummies` and used the suggestions in @Praneeth's link.